# Circular reference in Help --> Other (aka "contact us directly")

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

This rough diagram should explain what I mean: ([reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other))

> [image]

The "If your issue was not covered above, please feel free to contact us directly" line should be removed from the page it's referring to. :)

Comment: [Loop](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169464/circular-reference-in-help-other-aka-contact-us-directly#comment-500228)

Comment: Isn't it a bug?

Comment: @hims056 no, maybe bad design or simple overlook but don't think it's deserved to be called a bug. Nothing breaks. :-)

Comment: Perhaps you should better make that [a support question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other). Or if not, contact them directly...

Comment: @Bart lol, that's a good one! ;)

Comment: @hims056 Isn't that specifically recursion? ;)

Comment: @J.Steen it's oscillation.

Comment: @J.Steen - Lack of coffee. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's TWO times today I've missed using that meme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not relevant anymore with the new [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/152859) having such [contact page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact):

> [image]

Much cleaner, simpler and above all - no more circular reference. :)